Rendering Bookdown as Word doc
I am new to bookdown and currently trying to set it up and use for writing but having an issue rendering it as a word doc and it feels like a silly thing to be struggling with.
Context
I want to add the ability to render as a Word doc as some of my collaborators do not code. I added it to the YAML output file (_output.yml) as a download option (in the header, docx as I read it needs to represent the file extension) and added it as a bookdown output (word_document2) but when I render the book and try to use the download as word option from the HTML document, I get a "file not found" error. When I try to knit directly from RStudio to Word, it simply renders an HTML file. I can see in the "_book" folder the epub and pdf file, so I understand why there is an error about the file not being found, however I do not understand why it will not knit to a Word doc.
To reproduce this:

Create a new project and specify "Book project using bookdown" as the Project Type
Open the _output.yml script and edit to look as follows:

bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit: https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/edit/BRANCH/%s
    download: ["pdf", "epub", "docx"]
    sharing: null
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
bookdown::word_document2:
  toc: true


Knit the book from the index.Rmd file
Click the download button (see red circled button below) from the upper right and select DOCX


System information:

> xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1, RStudio 2024.4.0.735

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3   bslib_0.6.1      
  cachem_1.0.8      cli_3.6.2        
  digest_0.6.34     ellipsis_0.3.2   
  evaluate_0.23     fastmap_1.1.1    
  fontawesome_0.5.2 fs_1.6.3         
  glue_1.7.0        graphics_4.3.2   
  grDevices_4.3.2   highr_0.10       
  htmltools_0.5.7   jquerylib_0.1.4  
  jsonlite_1.8.8    knitr_1.45       
  lifecycle_1.0.4   magrittr_2.0.3   
  memoise_2.0.1     methods_4.3.2    
  mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1         
  rappdirs_0.3.3    rlang_1.1.3      
  rmarkdown_2.25    sass_0.4.8       
  stats_4.3.2       stringi_1.8.3    
  stringr_1.5.1     tinytex_0.50     
  tools_4.3.2       utils_4.3.2      
  vctrs_0.6.5       xfun_0.41        
  yaml_2.3.8       

Pandoc version: 3.1.11

Thank you all in advance!
